# Integral of complex function involving cosine

Tags: complex-analysis

$$\int_{0}^{π/2} 1/(2+ \cos(\theta))d\theta$$

My approach: I used the Euler formula for $\cos\theta$ where $\cos(z) = (e^{i\theta} + e^{-i\theta})/2$ = and the substitution $z = e^{i}$.

Now the problem is that after the problem is asking for $\cos(\theta)$ not for the $\cos(z)$. Can someone work me through this?

Comment: Either transform your integral into one over infinite bounds using cancellation symmetry or at least consider a contour out from $0$ to $\pi / 2$, probably closed as a semicircle to use the circular symmetry to get easy estimates

Answer (score 0):

You may approach by the $$ \cos \theta =\frac {1-\tan ^2 \theta /2}{1+\tan ^2 \theta /2}$$

Then let $$u=\tan \theta /2$$ 
$$ du =(1/2)(1+\tan^2\theta/2)d\theta$$

It will change your integral to a more manageable one..

Comment: hi, thank you very much, I think this is using trigonometry identity, but I think this question is supposed to be solved using complex analysis, as that is the topic I am learning right now. Thanks in advance!